# Azure Automation Hybrid On-Prem Linux Worker won't accept jobs

Tags: azure, azure-automation

**On-Prem VM**
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
4GB mem
2 CPU

I've followed https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/automation/automation-linux-hrw-install#install-a-linux-hybrid-runbook-worker

It's reporting to Log Analytics. And it shows up in "Hybrid Worker Groups" under "Automation Account".

And no fw is active on VM.

But, when I run a Python Runbook on the "Hybrid Worker" the job is Queued for some time, then later it's Suspended. What am I doing wrong?

"/home/nxautomation/run" is empty, maybe the worker is'nt running?

Answer (score 0):

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/automation/troubleshoot/hybrid-runbook-worker) has necessary information on troubleshooting your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable AzOperationalInsightsIntelligencePack!

```
<rg> = ResourceGroup of your Automation-Account
<workspace = Name of your Automation-Account

Set-AzOperationalInsightsIntelligencePack -ResourceGroupName <rg> -WorkspaceName <workspace> -IntelligencePackName "AzureAutomation" -Enabled $true
```

**Result:**

[image]

Then try again ...